# Filling an array of objects to create consecutive keys

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a heatmap depending on the markers for a given year. I start from an array that looks like this:

```
[{ 
  year: -400;
  markers: 3;
},
{ 
  year: -330;
  markers: 10;
},
{ 
  year: -20;
  markers: 32;
},
...
{ 
  year: 103;
  markers: 11;
}
...
]
```

So how could I fill the array with consecutive years from the beginning (-400) to the current year (2022) with markers at 0?

```
[{ 
  year: -400;
  markers: 3;
},
{ 
  year: -339;
  markers: 0;
},
{ 
  year: -338;
  markers: 0;
},
...
{ 
  year: -330;
  markers: 10;
},
...
{ 
  year: 2021;
  markers: 0;
},
{ 
  year: 2022;
  markers: 0;
}
]
```

The point is to get a final array of hex depending on the number of markers of each year to use it on a gradient CSS background.

```
['#DEDEDE', '#F9DB88', ..., '#DEDEDE'...]
```

============

**UPDATE**

What I want to achieve is to make this slider heatmap:
[image]

The data that I receive from the services are two different arrays, one of biographies that looks like this:

[image]

and another one of milestones, which looks like this:

[image]

So, thanks to @Eugene's answer, I was thinking to make a dictionary with the following format:

```
{year: births.length + deaths.length + locations.length}
```

from the oldest year (-1350000) to the current year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order not to run through the array thousands of times looking for values, I suggest creating a dictionary:

```js
const arr = [
  { 
    year: -400,
    markers: 3,
  },
  ...
];
const dict = Object.fromEntries(arr.map((a) => [a.year, a.markers]));
let result = [];
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (let i = -400; i <= currentYear; i++) {
  result.push({
    year: i,
    markers: dict[i] ?? 0,
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

According to the update of the question, piece of the solution based on the stackblitz:

```js
forkJoin([this.bios$, this.milestones$])
  .pipe(map(([bios, milestones]) => {
    const dict = {};
    bios.forEach((bio) => {
      dict[bio.year] = bio.births.length + bio.deaths.length;
    });
    milestones.forEach((ms) => {
      dict[ms.year] = (dict[ms.year] ?? 0) + ms.locations.length;
    });
    // colors...

    this.minSlider = Math.min(...Object.keys(dict).map((key) => Number(key)));

    const gradient = [];
    for (let i = this.minSlider; i <= this.maxSlider; i++) {
      if (!dict[i]) { // 0 or undefined
        gradient.push(color0);
      } // else if ...
    }

    return gradient;
  }))
```

But I'm not sure if CSS (browser) can display a gradient of hundreds of thousands of values :)

If there are a lot of repeating colors (in particular zeros) as the first iteration, I would look towards removing duplicate colors in exchange for putting down the position as a percentage.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful... However, I'm having some troubles in my project, because I need to join two different arrays: https://jsfiddle.net/ytgLpmux/ Could you please take a look?

Comment: Look like you just concat arrays, but do you need to join them by year? And can you provide a workable example at stackblitz?

Comment: I do need to join them by year... There you go the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bcszsh?file=src/app/hello.component.ts) . But it's giving this error: `Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2019' or later.` (Tried to change the 'lib' compiler option and still doesn't work...

Comment: Hm, I created an issue for them :)
So, we can create a dictionary in another way, but I don't get what you're comparing and calculating, see https://angular-ivy-der24u.stackblitz.io

Comment: Sorry, @Eugene, I'm not able to load the site... It stucks loading. I've just update my question to better explain my goal.

Comment: That update works great! Many many thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop and push the unknown values!

```js
const arr = [{ 
  year: -400,
  markers: 3,
},
{ 
  year: -330,
  markers: 10,
},
{ 
  year: -20,
  markers: 32,
},
{ 
  year: 103,
  markers: 11,
}
];
let output = [];
const currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
for(let i = -400; i <= currentYear; i++) {
  const found = arr.find(x => x.year === i);
  if(found) {
    output.push(found);
  } else {
    output.push({
      year: i,
      markers: 0,
    });
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: calling `(new Date()).getFullYear()` at each step of the loop kills performance.

`for(let i=-400;i<=(new Date()).getFullYear();i++) {}` — 2.5k ops/s.

`const y = new Date().getFullYear(); for(let i=-400;i<=y;i++) {}` — 635k ops/s.

Comment: @Eugene My bad, thank you for pointing out that!

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Explanation is in comment.

```js
let data = [{
    year: -400,
    markers: 3,
  },
  {
    year: -330,
    markers: 10,
  },
  {
    year: -20,
    markers: 32,
  },
  {
    year: 103,
    markers: 11,
  }
];

// variable for result array
let result = [];
// loop over years
for (let year = -400; year <= 2022; year++) {
  // filter your data and check if marker exist for selected year
  let arr = data.filter(d => d.year == year);
  // if exists then push that value else add new object with marker = 0
  if (arr.length > 0)
    result.push(arr[0]);
  else
    result.push({
      year: year,
      markers: 0
    });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first create an placeholder array and then start to replace the values

```js
// start with those years
const start = [{
    year: -400,
    markers: 3,
  },
  {
    year: -330,
    markers: 10,
  },
  {
    year: -20,
    markers: 32,
  },
  {
    year: 103,
    markers: 11,
  }
];

// your first and last year
const firstYear = start[0].year;
const lastYear = start[start.length - 1].year;

// calculate the timespan between the years
const years = lastYear - firstYear;


// build an empty array with markers as 0
const res = Array.from({
  length: years
}).map((_, i) => ({
  year: firstYear + i,
  markers: 0
}));


// replace the years that you have a value for
const yearNumbers = res.map(year => year.year);
for (let existing of start) {
  const overwrite = yearNumbers.indexOf(existing.year);
  if (overwrite === -1) {
    break;
  }

  res[overwrite] = existing;
}


console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not actually need to fill in your initial array with the missing values. You could do something like this (it's more efficient from a memory point of view and depending on how you use this data, it might be at least ok from a processing time point of view also):

```
let data = [
  {
    year: -400,
    markers: 3,
  },
  {
    year: -399,
    markers: 10,
  },
  {
    year: -396,
    markers: 10,
  },
];

let availableYears = [];

data.forEach((obj) => availableYears.push(obj.year));

const startYear = data[0].year;
const endYear = data[data.length - 1].year;

for (year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  if (!availableYears.includes(year)) {

  /*Here you would use however you want the fact that 
  you know that the markers for this year are missing.
  For the purpose of this example, I just logged the value
  you would have inserted in the array with your approach*/

    console.log({
      year,
      markers: 0,
    });
  }
}
```

This approach could be a lot more efficient especially for a sparse `data` array (one with a lot of missing years).

A stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1bsmeh?file=index.js